# Silverstripe on souceforge project web

Tags: sourceforge, silverstripe, web-applications

how do I install silverstripe on sourceforge for a project. I know I need a synlink...but I don't know how to?

I have a htdocs folder that is read only (once on the server) that I can access via sftp 
     it is accsesable via url

I have a persistent folder that is rightable (once on the server) that I can access via sftp
     it is not accsesable via url

I have a mysql credentials that are accseped during install but can't be finished because of no right accsess

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to install SilverStripe on sourceforge? Well, okay.

I guess you need to check that the MySQL user you're using has write access to the database. Also, that you got the database name right in the installation process: if you didn't, the installer will try to create that database, and if you don't have the necessary permission (usually the case on shared hosting setups), you'll get an error complaining about the CREATE DATABASE statement.

Answer (score 0):

So do I understand it right that your problem is that you can upload SilverStripe, but you can not install it, because the installer wants to write the config file?

Well, in this case there is actually a way to get SilverStripe running without using the installer. Just enter the database information into your mysite/_config.php file.
It should look something like this:

```
    <?php

    global $project;
    $project = 'mysite';

    global $databaseConfig;
    $databaseConfig = array(
            "type" => 'MySQLDatabase',
            "server" => 'localhost',
            "username" => 'myuser',
            "password" => 'mypass',
            "database" => 'mydatabasename',
            "path" => '',
    );

    MySQLDatabase::set_connection_charset('utf8');

    // This line set's the current theme. More themes can be
    // downloaded from http://www.silverstripe.org/themes/
    SSViewer::set_theme('blackcandy');

    // Set the site locale
    i18n::set_locale('en_US');

    // enable nested URLs for this site (e.g. page/sub-page/)
    SiteTree::enable_nested_urls();

    Director::set_environment_type('dev');
    // Director::set_environment_type('live');
```

please note that SilverStripe by default requires write permission on the assets/ folder, not only for uploading files, it also requires it for saving CSS files if the environment type is set to live, because SilverStripe wants to fetch all JS and CSS files, combine them into 1 single JS and 1 CSS file and saves them into the assets/ folder.
If this is not possible, the admin will simply not load, you can also work around this by letting SilverStripe generate those files on another server (your local dev server) and then upload the files.